# How to display UIToolBar always from LTR?

Tags: ios, localization

My app has a `UIToolBar` with many `UIBarButtonItem`s.

like this image:

[image: LTR UIToolBar]

But when I made the app localizable, When an `RTL` language selected the `UIToolBar` become like this:

[image: RTL UIToolBar]

How I can display `UIBarButtonItem`s always from `LTR` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this option in **Attribute inspector**,
After you select the *Toolbar*

[image]